# Can I use Azure Key Vault to secure my keys for an application running on an AWS instance?

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, azure-keyvault

We have our server instances running both on AWS and Azure for different clients. We want to use a key management service to safegaurd our production keys. Can Azure Key Vault be used as a solution for this ? Will it be supported for server running on AWS instance ?

Comment: what are you running? VMs?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu Instances, both on AWS and Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Azure key Vault to secure keys for your app running in both AWS and Azure.

If you look at the pseudo code snippet to access Azure Key Vault,

```
//extend KeyVaultCredentials class and override doAuthenticate method.  

// create a configuration object 

Configuration config = KeyVaultConfiguration.configure(null, keyVaultCredentials);
KeyVaultClient myclient = KeyVaultClientService.create(config);

//encrypt
myclient.encryptAsync(...)

//decrypt
myclient.decryptAsync(...)
```

As the KeyVault services are available through SDK, you should be able to access the services from anywhere. It is just that you should have valid access credentials.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this and update how it goes.

Comment: But this again needs setting up active directory and service principal to be able to authenticate you.

Comment: That needs to be done even if you want to run it locally or on Azure right ?